# Can a member country exit the OECD?

Tags: oecd

I'm trying to find whether (and how) a member country can leave the OECD. I've searched through the (scarce) legal documents, including the actual accession agreements by individual countries, without success. It seems (and perhaps with due reason) the legal framework of the OECD does not consider such possibility as an option. Is anyone aware of this issue?

Some links to legal documents [here](https://www.oecd.org/legal/accession-process.htm) and [here](https://www.oecd.org/legal/oecd-convention.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can a member country exit the OECD?

Apparently, yes.

[Convention on the Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development](https://www.oecd.org/general/conventionontheorganisationforeconomicco-operationanddevelopment.htm)

> ***Article 17***
>
> Any Contracting Party may terminate the application of this Convention to itself by giving twelve months' notice to that effect to the depositary Government.

The "depositary Government" is "the Government of the French Republic" (Article 14).

Comment: But wait, that is the 1960's convention. Is it still valid?

Comment: @luchonacho - [Convention on the OECD](https://www.oecd.org/legal/oecd-convention.htm) states that the _Organisation for European Economic Co-operation ... was reconstituted as the Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development_. In other words, it appears that the original members agreed to a name change and expansion beyond Europe. To discontinue the former to create a new organization would have required ratification, of the new agreement, by the original members. Changing the objectives needs only a vote by the representatives.